# What is the smallest karanayan elite integer?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Let *s(n)* = the sum of the digits of *n*, and let *d(n)* = number of digits of *n* (with non negative integers *n*). A karanayan elite integer is a positive integer of the form $10^{8+9k}+8+9k$ that can be written **neither** of these six forms:

- *n+s(n)*
- *n+d(n)*
- *n+s(n)+d(n)*
- *n-s(n)*
- *n+s(n)-d(n)*
- *n-s(n)-d(n)*

For examples zero can be written as $0=0+s(0)=1-s(1)=2-s(2)$, so zero is not a karanayan elite integer. $1$ can be written as $1=0+d(0)=1+s(1)-d(1)=2-s(2)+d(2)=3-s(3)+d(3)$,etc, so $1$ is not a karanayan elite integer. 10 is also not a karanayan because $10=5+s(5)$, $21=15+s(15)$=$14+s(14)+d(14)$, $25=30-s(30)-d(30)$=$18+s(18)-d(18)$. in addition Zero, one , ten, $21$, and  $25$ are not of the form $10^{8+9k}+8+9k$.   The smallest karanayan elite integer (if it exists) must be a very very large number, it must be greater than $10^{65000}$. And also karanayan elite integers must be numbers of the form $10^m+m$, because numbers not of the form $10^m+m$ will always can be written as *n+d(n)*. Note that integers of the form$10^m+m$ will always can be written as $n-s(n)+d(n)$, see this pattern: $10^m+m=(10^m+1)-s(10^m+1)+d(10^m+1)$.  So what is the smallest karanayan elite integer ?

Comment: Welcome to mathexchange. It is common practice to provide some more information about the problem. e.g. where is the problem coming from, what have you tried, where are you stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked it up to $10^{60000}$ digits, and I wonder if such number can not exist